# What exactly does the AMD Ontario C-50 APU have?

Tags: gpu, multi-core

Does it come with two cores at 1 GHz plus a GPU, or is it just two cores and one of them is the GPU?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it has two processor cores PLUS one gpu integrated on the same chip.

Comment: Just one more thing. Are those cores hyper-threaded?

Comment: No. Hyperthreading technology occurs in mostly intel processor as it is a intel-specific technology.

Comment: Got it. So there's no AMD equivalent to this technology? And if there is, are they using it on these processors?

Comment: Well I don't think there is a close substitute. Not that hyperthreading is any useful anyways...